# Flutter : Container Background image + background color delete extra

Tags: flutter

i'm using a background image + white color for background
I want to delete excess white color,

[image]

code :

```
Container(
          height: 60,
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/ok_button_bg.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Change the colors to Colors.transparent and add another container as a child with a white background color

Comment: Is it  parallelogram shape?

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
      height: 60,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/ok_button_bg.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Remove the **color** property